# React Native Lottie: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I'm using the Lottie imperative API to display a looping animation.
The imperative API works fine on all of my components except one that uses [React Native Sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound). I assume the problem is that both libraries are called with `.play()`. Is this possible?

Lottie: `this.animation.play();`
React Native Sound: `this.sound.play()`

After calling the Lottie method, I'm getting the Error Message:

> Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be getting that error if `this.animation` or `this.sound` were undefined...

Comment: You're right. React Native Sound works though and `Animation` is imported with Lottie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. React Native Sound of course wasn't the problem - it might have just delayed the initialization of Lottie and thus `animation` was still undefined when I called it.

The solution is to build in a timer and was already suggested in this thread: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/issues/21

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.initAnimation();
  }

  initAnimation(){
    if (!this.animation){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.initAnimation();
      }, 100);
    } else {
        this.animation.play();
    }
  }
```